# Flutter Provider/Consumer UI not Updating with Data Change

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and working on developing my first application. I an having trouble updating my UI based on data changes. I followed this tutorial: https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-architecture-my-provider-implementation-guide/ (and added extra features with https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-provider-architecture-sharing-data-across-your-models/), which walks through a MVVM setup using the GetIt library.

I have successfully passed the data through the viewmodels and services, but I can't get my UI to update. Essentially, I want a user to be able to tap the movie on their watchlist and remove it. This works in a data sense, but my Watchlist UI isn't updating when I pop back to it. My entire project is available at https://github.com/n0ahth0mas/movie_night, but the core files to this problem are listed here:

*locator.dart*

```
...
...
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => AuthenticationService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => WatchlistService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => Api());

  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => LoginModel());
  locator.registerFactory(() => HomeModel());
  locator.registerFactory(() => RemoveButtonModel());
  locator.registerFactory(() => WatchlistModel());
}
```

*watchlist_service.dart*

```
...
...
class WatchlistService {
  Api _api = locator<Api>();

  List<Movie> _watchlist = [];
  List<Movie> get watchlist => _watchlist;

  Future getUserWatchlist(User user) async {
    for (String id in user.watchlistId) {
      _watchlist.add(await _api.getMovie(id));
    }
  }

  bool inList(Movie movie) {
    return _watchlist.contains(movie);
  }

  void editList(Movie movie, bool remove) {
    if (remove) {
      _watchlist.remove(movie);
      print("removed " + movie.title + " from list in watchlist service");
    } else {
      _watchlist.add(movie);
      print("added " + movie.title + " to list in watchlist service");
    }
  }
}
```

*watchlist_model.dart*

```
...
...
class WatchlistModel extends BaseModel {
  WatchlistService _watchlistService = locator<WatchlistService>();

  List<Movie> get watchlist => _watchlistService.watchlist;

  Future getWatchlist(User user) async {
    setState(ViewState.Busy);
    await _watchlistService.getUserWatchlist(user);
    setState(ViewState.Idle);
  }
}
```

*watchlist_view.dart*

```
...
...
class WatchlistView extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget _createMovieCard(Movie movie, BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoButton(
      onPressed: () => _getInfo(movie, context),
      child: Image.network(movie.getPoster(185)),
    );
  }

  _getInfo(Movie movie, BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      "details",
      arguments: movie,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<WatchlistModel>(
        onModelReady: (model) => model.getWatchlist(Provider.of<User>(context)),
        builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
            body: model.state == ViewState.Idle
                ? CustomScrollView(
                    primary: false,
                    slivers: <Widget>[
                      CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
                        largeTitle: Text("My Watchlist"),
                        trailing: Material(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add_circled_solid),
                                onPressed: () =>
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'search'))),
                      ),
                      SliverGrid(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            childAspectRatio:
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                    (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.7)),
                        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                            (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return _createMovieCard(
                              model.watchlist[index], context);
                        }, childCount: model.watchlist.length),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())));
  }
}
```

*removebtn_model.dart*

```
...
...

class RemoveButtonModel extends BaseModel {
  WatchlistService _watchlistService = locator<WatchlistService>();

  //bool watchlistStatus()

  void removeMovie(Movie movie) {
    print("removed " + movie.title + " from list in remove button model");
    _watchlistService.editList(movie, true);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addMovie(Movie movie) {
    print("added " + movie.title + " to list in remove button model");
    _watchlistService.editList(movie, false);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

*details_view.dart*

```
...
...
class DetailsView extends StatelessWidget {
  _makeStars(double voteAverage) {
    double trueRating = voteAverage / 2;
    print(trueRating);
    return GFRating(
      color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
      value: trueRating,
      size: GFSize.SMALL,
      allowHalfRating: true,
    );
  }

  _backdrop(String link) {
    if (link != null) {
      return Image.network("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/$link");
    } else
      return Image.asset("assets/images/transparent.png");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Movie movie = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
            largeTitle: Text(movie.title),
            trailing:
                Material(color: Colors.transparent, child: RemoveButton(movie)),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
              Center(child: Image.network(movie.getPoster(342))),
              Center(
                  child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(movie.title,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800))),
              )),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _makeStars(movie.voteAverage),
                    Text("platform",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 10, 50),
                child: Text(movie.overview),
              ),
              _backdrop(movie.backdropPath)
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*remove_btn.dart*

```
...
...
class RemoveButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Movie movie;
  RemoveButton(this.movie);

  _showDialog(String id, bool inWatchlist, BuildContext context,
      RemoveButtonModel model) {
    if (inWatchlist) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
              title: Text("Remove from your watchlist?"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                  isDefaultAction: true,
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(),
                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                ),
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  onPressed: () => _deletelist(id, context, model),
                  child: Text("Remove"),
                )
              ]));
    } else {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
              title: Text("Add to your watchlist?"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(),
                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                ),
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                  isDefaultAction: true,
                  onPressed: () => _addList(id, context, model),
                  child: Text("Add"),
                )
              ]));
    }
  }

  _deletelist(String id, BuildContext context, RemoveButtonModel model) {
    model.removeMovie(movie);
    Provider.of<User>(context).deleteFromWatchlist(id);
    //Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'watchlist');
    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('watchlist'));
  }

  _addList(String id, BuildContext context, RemoveButtonModel model) {
    model.addMovie(movie);
    Provider.of<User>(context).addToWatchList(id);
    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('watchlist'));
  }

  Widget _rightBtn(Movie movie, BuildContext context, RemoveButtonModel model) {
    if (Provider.of<User>(context).inWatchlist(movie)) {
      return IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () =>
              _showDialog(movie.id.toString(), true, context, model));
    } else {
      return IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () =>
              _showDialog(movie.id.toString(), false, context, model));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<RemoveButtonModel>(
      builder: (context, model, child) => _rightBtn(movie, context, model),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help! I've been stuck on this for the past 3 days and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: did you find a fix for this?